# Javascript Arguments object changes when changing the function argument?

Tags: javascript, arguments

Changing the value of an argument name changes the value that is retrieved through arguments[ ] array. Why is it so ? [JSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/ttvgnupc/)

```
var sum = 0;
function foo(x,y) {
  if(x)
  {
    x = null;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    sum += arguments[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
foo(10,20,30);
```

It outputs 50 which is not the intended behavior and should outputs 60.

Comment: but then my whole script will work as working in strict mode ?. Is there is any linking between argument object and function argument ?

Comment: You can `'use strict'` for a single function: http://jsfiddle.net/ttvgnupc/1/

Comment: @Vivek `"use strict";` can be applied INSIDE of functions -- the very first line, and it will only apply to the function.

Comment: Not to mention, changing arguments inside of a function is one of those well-known "Don't do that!".  EcmaScript, and EcmaScript 3 in particular, has some rough edges.  Stay away from them and don't do something [clever, silly, fun, hackish, painful, weird, strange].